# Why is python's del() specially treated?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I hit a bug with `dict( del = '...' )` where python doesn't allow `del` to be used as a key here - and looking into this a bit further I find `del` isn't allowed in a few other cases as well.

I'm trying to understand why [`del()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-del-statement) (and possibly other keywords?) is treated specially in cases where other keywords/identifiers would be perfectly acceptable (but perhaps not to best-practice).

```
>>> platform.python_version()
'3.8.5'

>>> dict( foo = 'bar' )
{'foo': 'bar'}

>>> dict( del = 'bar' )
File "<stdin>", line 1
dict( del = 'bar' )
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax   # but why?  dict( abs = 'bar' ) is ok

>>> dict( abs = 'foo' )
{'abs': 'foo'}

>>> type(abs)
<class 'builtin_function_or_method'>

>>> type(del)
File "<stdin>", line 1
type(del)
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax  # strange!! why? what gives `del` this special power?

>>> a = lambda foo,del: ''
File "<stdin>", line 1
a = lambda foo,del: ''
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

>>> a = lambda list, index: del(list, index)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
  a = lambda list, index: del(list, index)
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

There must be something special about `del()` or python's statement identifiers that cannot be used in such ways. I'd appreciate some insights into the reasoning for these limitations and possibly what can be done to work around them.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/What-are-Reserved-Keywords-in-Python

Comment: `del` is a keyword. `abs` the name of a built-in function. Different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because `del` is a keyword, just like `class`, `for`, `while`, `True`, `False` etc (the last 2 are keywords in Python 3 only).

The same behavior is reproduced when any of these is attempted to be used as an identifier. There is nothing special about `del` here.

```
dict(class=...)
dict(for=...)
dict(while=...)
dict(True=...)
dict(False=...)
```

You can still use any of these as a key in a dict, just not where a valid identifier is expected.

```
d = {'class': 'a'}
```

instead of

```
d = dict(class='a')
```

The difference between a keyword and a built-in function/global is that built-ins can be overwritten because they are not treated differently by the interpreter. Think of them as variables that someone else has already defined and assigned a function to for you, before your own code is executed. If you choose to overwrite them, it's your problem.

Keywords are a different story. They are treated as a special token by the parser/interpreter and mean something special. They can't be overwritten at run time.